# Show that the ideal generated by $4$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is not a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, solution-verification

> Show that the ideal generated by $4$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is not a prime ideal.

Hint: Give a counter-example

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. So lets begin:

Ideal generated  by $4$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}$ is given by: $I=\{0,4,8\}$ since, $2\times2= 4\in I$. But $2\notin I\Rightarrow I$ is not prime ideal.

I want thank you ahead of time for taking the time to look at this problem.

Comment: That is not rough but perfect. Well done. +1

Comment: $2\times 2=4$ is plenty simple. You took a perhaps once in a lifetime opportunity to use it in a proof.

Comment: your answer is true.

Comment: Similarly $\,(p)\,$ prime $\iff p\,$ prime $\Rightarrow\, p\,$ irreducible, if $\,p\ne 0\ \ $